# Power series Integration part of proof.

Tags: calculus

[image]

Now I get the proof, but then I came to this:

[image]

Now I do not get this statement cause in the previous case we were subtracting a number( so in this case if we were to subtract example c=-2, it would be the same as adding(do to - -) however why have we changed the inequaltiy to equality. Is this becaue we are adding a number H, or is there something els to it? I have not added the entire proof as I want to understand as much as possible by myself. I am only interested in the change to equality sign in front of K.

Comment: Also could someone show me where the latex error occur:$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left\left| a_n\right\right|  (\left| x\right| +H)^n$

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left| a_n\right|  (\left| x\right| +H)^n$. Is this what you meant? If so then you should remove the double \left and \right. There should always be a bracket or a dot following \left or \right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he's just saying that it converges.  The equality there just means that the infinite sum converges to some finite number less than infinity.  That's what it means for a sum to converge -- to equal some finite real number.